# Which are the vipassana jhanas?

Tags: theravada, vipassana

Which are the vipassana jhanas? What are the differences with the jhanas? Where can I find more information about them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see Ven. Gunaratana's ["The Jhanas"](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/gunaratana/wheel351.html). He gave pretty detailed descriptions of the standard jhanas versus the vipassana one, what's called "momentary concentration"/khanikaSamadhi.